# A links not working at certain breakpoints?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, navigation

Noticed an issue with my website http://www.feelunreal.co.uk

For some reason the a links aren't working when the browser width is below 1280px all the way down to 767px. I'm referring to the menu bar (top left) and Social Media Links (top right).

I don't have any media queries that might be affecting them at this point and I thought it might have been something to do with z-index but after eliminating that I can't solve this problem. It's so odd because it works above 1280px perfectly fine.

I have a separate menu for mobile devices and this seems fine also.

Just need a new pair of eyes to maybe notice something I'm missing or where I've gone wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]please check your main.css file line number 211..
you have to add this property where you defined the  element `z-index:99999;`

so it will look like this.

```
nav {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999999;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Gave the nav a z-index:999 and the h3 z-index: 888 which has fixed it. :)

Answer (score 1):

you have a h3 that blocks the links:

```
<h3>Feel Unreal</h3>
```

this h3 inherits this class: `.f2-f3` which have the following percentage as width that blocks only when your window width is under a specific width: `width: 81.70572917%;`
this looks like a calculated width, which changes when the window size changes.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Gave the nav a z-index:999 and the h3 z-index: 888 which has fixed it. :)

Answer (score 0):

your `<h3>` lays over the navigation.
append a higher z-index to the navigation section.

Answer (score -1):

I would just put a style to the  that the links are in with a higher z-index than other elements example:(style="z-index:9999999;"), that would be the easy and fast fix.

Comment: this could cause unexpected results, like when you try to open a popup, the links that supposed to be underneath goes up above the pop up

Comment: This is a one page scrolling website, there is no popups. So, no problem at all. But, i don't disagree with you that this cuold cause a problem with popups or anything, but in this case, it would be just fine. Easy and fast fix, like i said.